# printer communite(bat) with webapi(php)

Tags: php, batch-file, zebra-printers, printers

I need to communicate a printer (zebra) with an api (php).

Example, you have a new data on the server, you must have a baton that checks this every 10 seconds, and send the file to the printer (the printer is on the computer).

But I have no idea how to do it, because I want to make it generic.
I'm trying to use the electron, but it's not working. If anyone has any ideas, I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0):

On Server

```
<?
$new="1.txt";
   if(file_exists($new)){
    exec('print /d:\\Network\printer1 c:\accounting\report.txt');
    echo "ok";
   }
?>
```

//on your PC

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="start()">Start printing...</button>
<script>
function start(){
    setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:"http://yourserver.ro/print.php", 
    type:"post", 
    data:({test:"test"}),
    success: function(rsp){ 
    if(rsp=="ok"){
        alert('printing...!')
    };
}});
},3000)}

</script>
```

Comment: The printer is mapped to the computer, not the server.
How can I communicate the server with the printer installed on my computer?

Comment: On your PC you can add this on php page.
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> reload page every 10 sec, to test php script

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="start()">Start printing...</button>
<script>
function start(){
    setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:"http://alertweb.com.br/printer/index.php", 
    type:"post", 
    data:({test:"test"}),
    success: function(rsp){ 
    if(rsp=="ok"){
        console.log('printing...!')
    };
}});
},3000)}

</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: <?php
$new="Teste.pdf";
   if(file_exists($new)){
    exec('print /d:\\127.0.0.1\Sweda c:\Teste.pdf');
    echo "ok";
   }
?>

Comment: the printer not receive a request